# Are ajax requests guaranteed to hit the server in order?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the **order of completion** is not guaranteed.

I interpret this to mean that your then/done/always/fail callbacks are not guaranteed to fire in the order the requests went out. This makes sense if you're calling different API endpoints and some take longer than others.

What I want to know is if you're making ajax requests to the same API endpoint, are they guaranteed to reach the server in order?

I've written some code that autosaves a draft as you type, and I want to know if I'm guaranteed to always be saving the latest copy of the draft, or if it's possible that an older ajax request will come in after a newer one and then my PHP code will cause the newer draft to be overwritten with an older one. It doesn't matter in which order the requests *return*; just the order they're *received* matters.

I can conceive of a way to fix this, I just want to know if it's necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests can arrive in ANY order that the network(s) involved decide to deliver the packets in.

e.g.

request #1 at timepoint 0.000 takes route A
request #2 at timepoint 0.123 takes route B

but suddenly a backhoe cuts the fibre cable handling route A, causing the network to reroute through route C, which uses an [RFC 1149](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) carrier, causing a 12 hour delay in arrival. So at the server, you end up getting

request #2 arrives at timepoint 0.173, taking a nice "slow" 50ms route
request #1 arrives at timepoint 12:00:00:0.50, having taken longer route.

Comment: If the requests are made on separate TCP connections, then their ordering is not guaranteed; but if they are sent over the same connection (which is possible with HTTP 2.0), then their ordering will be guaranteed by the underlying TCP stream. As always, whether a browser supports HTTP 2.0, and how it handles AJAX requests specifically is a crapshoot; but the server must support HTTP 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 2):

As with anything asynchronous, the answer is a confident "Maybe!"

Just because your JavaScript engine triggered a series of callbacks in a particular order does not mean the server will receive them in the same order, and it especially does not mean they will wrap up in the same order.

If one of these requests stalls due to packet loss, gets held up by a load balancer, or ends up delayed for any of a myriad of reasons it would fall out of sequence. Since these events are not uncommon, the safest bet is they will be issued in random order and completed in random order.

If you need them to happen sequentially you'll have to wait for one to finish before triggering the next.

Comment: I was with you until the end. I don't think I have to wait for one to finish before triggering the next. I just have to attach a sequential counter to the ajax requests and then, on the server, drop any that are lower than the greatest number received to date. Possibly watching for integer overflows. But if I only fire one every 500ms, that buys me 34 years on a 32-bit signed int.

Comment: @mark Oh, if you can alter the API to have a sequence identifier, absolutely. I was just talking about sequencing in general theory with a generic API you have no control over. If you have the ability to ignore out-of-order requests, `new Date().getTime()` values will work if you send calls fairly frequently but not aggressively, or a random 31-bit integer combined with a client session identifier for other situations.